# Jstree call event when context menu is shown and hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, jstree

I'm trying to call some javascript code when a context menu is show and is hidden (*shown being when I right click and the context menu appears; hidden being when I click outside the context menu and it disappears from the page*). I tried the following but the events never get fired.

```
// Create instance for tree
$(function () {
    $('#myTree').jstree({
        "core": {
            "themes": {
                'name': 'default',
                "variant": "small",
                "icons": false
            }
        },
        "contextmenu": {
            "items": getMenu(),
            "select_node": false
        }
        ,"plugins": ["contextmenu"]
    });

});

// when context menu is shown
$("#myTree").bind('context_show.vakata', function (reference, element, position) {

    // code to do...
});

// when context menu is hidden
$("#myTree").bind('context_hide.vakata', function (reference, element, position) {

    // code to do...
});
```

The syntax appears correct according to the [API](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=context_show.vakata). Please help with what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the API says - the events are triggered on the document, so replace:
`$("#myTree").bind` with `$(document).bind`

Best regards,
Ivan